# Async / Await Lambdas

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

I have a strange problem combining the async/await to make it work:
I created a small procedure, which should handle basically the try/catch of every action:

```
    internal static void HandledAction(Action action, Info infoBar)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            infoBar.SetError("An Exception occured: " + ex.Message);
            WriteLog(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

Nohing to fancy, but it's worth since changing error-handling is very easy made.
But what happens, if I'd like to get Data async in the Lambda? Lets take this simple example:

```
    private void mnuImportData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActionHelper.HandledAction(async () =>
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Ups");
        }, infoMain);
    }
```

Sure, the HandledAction gets called, passes, since it gets the pointer back, and the exception gets thrown, of course not handled.

I imagine I have to create a AsyncHandledAction, and set the action async, but is there a easier way to solve this problem?

I guess many people use a central exception-handling, and there are far better solutions for this?

Thanks in advance

Matthias

Edit: I created an example, which should shpw netter I need: I basically dont want the whole Action I pass being awaitable, but one call in the Lambda is:

```
ActionHelper.HandledActionAsync(() =>
        {
            //elided
            CheckFileResult rslt = await excelImport.CheckFilesAsync(tmpPath);
            //elided
        }, infoMain);
```

Of course, by doing so, I get the error:

Error   3   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.

Comment: `async () => { }` can match both `Action` and `Func<Task>`. If it matches the former, it is like having the method signature `async void F()`; the latter, `async Task F()`. In your case you are getting `async void F()` which has fire-and-forget semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an async version of HandleAction

```
internal static async Task HandledAction(Func<Task> action, Info infoBar)
{
    try
    {
        await action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        infoBar.SetError("An Exception occured: " + ex.Message);
        WriteLog(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

of course you should call the method with await

```
private async void mnuImportData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ActionHelper.HandledAction(async () =>
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Ups");
    }, infoMain);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason is: **Action** instead of **Func**. Since yours:

```
async () =>
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Ups");
        }
```

in fact is:

```
async void Method() { }
```

when `Func<Task>` is:

```
async Task Method() { }
```

Async void will capture `SynchronizationContext.Current` and when exception is thrown it will be posted to `SynchronizationContext` by `SynchronizationContext.Post()` - (in windows runtime you can catch these types of exception). In case of `ASP.NET/Console application` `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns null which means that exception would be propagated to Thread Pool and I'm not sure but I think it is not possible to catch it.  However when there is returned `Task` by asynchronous method exception could be marshaled to the caller through this returned Task. It is also worth mention that async lambda expresions will always prefer methods with `Func<Task>` over `Action`. General rule is: never use `async void` (`async Action`) unless it is "top-level method" (in example event handler).

Comment: I think this is not much of a problem since the idea of the whole thing is to handle all exceptions

Comment: you can't catch any exception the way you do it unless you will have Func<Task> / async Task method.

Comment: I think I got it, as Stilgar said, I basically needto map the async to the call and I need a Func<Task> to get the exception, thanks so far