# async lambda not awaiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda

I have an extension method called `Use` that takes an `Action` as an argument:

```
IEnumerable<User> users;

service.Use(client => {
    users = client.GetUsers();
});

// users has a value now
```

When I go to use the `async` version of `GetUsers()`:

```
IEnumerable<User> users;

service.Use(async (client) => {
    users = await client.GetUsersAsync();
});

// users is null
```

...then the line `// users is null` is reached before `await client.GetUsersAsync()` returns a result.

How do I make sure that if my `Action`'s body includes any `await` keyword, execution doesn't continue past `Use()` before the `await` in the `Action`'s body is finished?

Note that I can't change the signature of `Use()`. The `Action` argument cannot be changed to a `Func`.

Comment: if your `Use` extension accepts `Action` then your async labda is being converted to `async void`. Try to change argument of `Use` from `Action` to `Func<Task>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Async / Await Lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647062/async-await-lambdas)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the signature of `Use` if you want the async lambda to be awaited:

```
Task Use(Func<Task> action)
{
  await action();
}
```

and then await it:

```
await service.Use(async (client) => {
  users = await client.GetUsersAsync();
});
```

If you can't do that, your only option is to wait for the task to complete instead of awaiting it (which defeats the purpose of using the async method in the first place):

```
service.Use((client) => {
  users = client.GetUsersAsync().Result;
});
```